# Better Performance and Control When Running a Full Windowing System in WSLg

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, rdp, weston

As for creating a root window in WSLg (e.g. for running a full Desktop Environment) there have been several options, but performance varies between them. I've tried several methods for having better performance/smoothness mentioned below. Is it possible to take control of WSLg rdp connection manually?

- Using X servers in Windows: Only good in multiwindow mode, probably because of:

  `AIGLX: No native OpenGL in modes with a root window`
- VNC/Xrdp: Slow compared to other methods.
- Using FreeRDP implementation in WSLg: Probably has the best performance overall (by using Xwayland as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385747/1589384)).

These almost always perform "better" when using `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`.

In order to have some features of rdp and X servers which the WSLg does not provide (like key hooks) and also having more control over it, I tried Weston with `--backend=rdp-backend.so`, but the performance was not close to the third option above (even with several optimizations). I tried removing msrdc/mstsc executables from Windows and making a direct connection from mstsc, which ended in `Error code 0x4`.

Edit: There seems to be some useful tweaks [here](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/wiki/WSLg-Configuration-Options-for-Debugging) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files), but in practice not using `remoteapplicationmode:i:1` leads to a poor and laggy result.

Comment: I wish I had more time to dig into this one, but it's probably going to be a while before I can dedicate the time it would need.  My recommendation would be to see how much you can reverse engineer the [WSLg System Distribution](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#wslg-system-distro).  As Microsoft says, they *"do want to encourage folks to tinker with it and experiment. Although [they] expect very few folks to actually need or want to do that, [they]'ve shared detailed instruction on [their] contributing page on how to both build and deploy a private version of the system distro."*