# StartXCFE4 with Vcxsrv doesn't work

Tags: xfce, windows-subsystem-for-linux

- WSL Version:  1.0.3.0
- Ubuntu Version:  22.04.1 LTS

Vcxsrv is still black.

I added `export DISPLAY=:172.X.XXX.X:0.0` in my `.bashrc` file.

When I run the command, `sudo startxfce4`, I have this message:

```
(xfwm4:4818): xfwm4-WARNING **: 15:06:25.234: Could not find a screen to manage, exiting

(xfsettingsd:4826): libupower-glib-WARNING **: 15:06:25.308: Couldn’t connect to proxy: Could not connect: No such file or directory
xfsettingsd: Another clipboard manager is already running.

(xfsettingsd:4826): xfsettingsd-WARNING **: 15:06:25.656: Failed to get the _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS property.
```

Answer (score 2):

A few problems to solve:

- First, you are attempting to run `startxfce4` using `sudo`.  This is a problem because (a) you really don't want to run your desktop as root, and (b) `sudo` by default doesn't pass environment variables from your user to the `sudo` session, so there's no `DISPLAY` set.
- Second, even if you run as your normal user, Xfce4 will see the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variable that WSLg provides and will refuse to run since Wayland on WSL is provided by Weston, which provides its own window manager (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385747/1165986) for details).

I was able to get Xfce4 running with a full-screen VcXsrv session using the following:

- Run Xlaunch with "One window without titlebar", "Start no client", and "Disable access control".
- In Ubuntu:

  ```
  export DISPLAY=$(hostname).local:0
  export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=
  startxfce4
  ```

  The `export DISPLAY` form that I use there works *regardless* of the IP address of WSL, the WSL2 network switch, or Windows itself.  It does require that you use the built-in WSL2 resolver, however.
- This will probably also require a firewall rule.  Typically, Windows Defender will generate a dialog box asking you to approve or deny the connection *the first time it is used*.  If you've made a connection in the past, then this rule may have been created for you.  However, if you missed the dialog box (it sometimes pops up *behind* other windows), then a "deny" rule may have been put into place that you'll need to fix.