# WSL 2 GUI trouble - Can't open Synaptic nor pluma with using the sudo command

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL 2 and the Mate Desktop Environment. I can log in via xrdp. I can browse the system and the internet but I'm missing some features like opening synaptic or open an editor with the sudo command. Also some settings from within the control center does not open and I'm not able to change the desktop language.
Is there a workaround with installing some needed packages to get that managed? Or by editing some files and rights?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

##### Summary

The question is a bit light in details, but I think I can reproduce much (if not all) of it.  There are likely two problems that are causing the issues listed in the question:

- WSL's current lack of Systemd support
- The root user needs a link to `.Xauthority`

##### Installation

Ok, let's start with the installation process to make sure we are on the same page.  In a new WSL/Ubuntu 20.04 instance, I did the following:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop xrdp synaptic
# Selected lightdm for login during install, but I don't think it matters
sudo cp /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini.bak
sudo sed -i 's/3389/3390/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
echo "mate-session" > ~/.xsession
```

Created `~/.xsessionrc` with:

```
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=mate
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:mate
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/mate:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-mate:/etc/xdg
```

And then started `xrdp` via:

```
sudo service xrdp start
```

##### Initial startup

At that point, I was able to use Windows Remote Desktop Connection on `localhost:3390` to connect to the MATE desktop.

I immediately received an error with `blueman-applet` crashing.  No real surprise here, since WSL doesn't have Bluetooth support, but I probably wouldn't expect a crash.  Running `blueman-applet` from the terminal shows more info, culminating in:

```
__bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SYSTEM)
gi.repository.GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: Could not connect: No such file or directory (1)
```

Hmm.  Sounds like a bus problem.  Let's come back to that one ...

A few moments later, I get another crash from `update-manager`. Again, running from the terminal shows me:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Okay, we definitely have some issues.  You may not even be noticing these at this point since those errors seem to be suppressed after the first occurrence.

##### sudo issues

```
> sudo pluma does_this_work.txt
No protocol specified
Cannot open display: 
Run 'pluma --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

A similar problem occurs with Synaptic.

This is fairly easily solved via [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240415/432493):

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/.Xauthority /root
```

Now `sudo synaptic` and `sudo pluma` work correctly.

##### Can't change language and other settings problems

Attempting to open *Language Settings* from the *Control Center* results in the window attempting to display but then crashing immediately.  Again, let's look at the terminal output of `gnome-language-selector`:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Hey, I'm sensing a pattern here ...

##### The root cause and (hopefully) solution

Gnome requires Systemd.  WSL does not use Systemd, but instead uses its own `/init` as PID1.  See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328686/1165986) for some details on what it does.  Most importantly for this discussion, note that it appends the Windows path to the Linux/WSL path and handles Interop so that you can launch Windows `.exe`cutables.

It is possible to make Ubuntu in WSL think that Systemd is in control, and we need to do that in order for Gnome to work properly.

I'm going to give you the simplest possible solution.  It is *not* necessarily the *best* solution.  Because it is "barebones", you will lose the ability to run Windows `.exe`cutables.  You will also lose the Windows path, but since that's really only useful for running Windows programs anyway, we'll consider that part of the same limitation.

If you want a more complex solution that attempts to solve this, look to some of the answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55579342/11810933), specifically [Genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) or [WSL2 Hacks](https://github.com/shayne/wsl2-hacks).

But all of these are just more complex versions of this:

```
sudo -b unshare --pid --fork --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=multi-user.target
```

This starts Systemd in a new namespace with its own PID mapping. Inside that namespace, Systemd will be PID1 (as it must, to function properly) and own all other processes. However, the "real" PID mapping still exists outside that namespace.

Wait a few seconds, run `ps -ef`.  If you see a number of `/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd` processes, then Systemd is still starting up.  Give it a moment and try again.

Note that `systemd` is *not* yet PID1.  That's because we have *created* the namespace, but we haven't *entered* it yet.

When the process list "settles down", Systemd is ready to go.  On my system, that's really only 5 seconds or so.  At that point, enter the namespace with:

```
sudo -E nsenter --all --wd="$PWD" -t $(pgrep -xo systemd) runuser -P -l $USER -c "exec $SHELL"
```

Doing a `ps -ef` at this point will show `systemd` as PID1, along with all of the other services that it brings up.

Best practice is to disable any Systemd units that you don't need, but it's not necessary to get things from MATE running better.

Now that we are in the Systemd namespace:

```
sudo systemctl start xrdp
sudo systemctl status xrdp
```

And then try connecting via RDP.

At this point, things are working about as well as I think you could ask:

- You can change your language (takes effect after logging out of MATE and reconnecting via RDP)
- You can access the Users & Groups settings, Disk settings, etc.
- You cannot access Bluetooth, since there is no hardware support, but at least it gives the proper message now, rather than crashes.
- You should not do any network or firewall configuration, as WSL still needs to manage this

##### Note

Once you have started Systemd in an instance, it "takes over".  At startup, it creates numerous files and starts processes.  If you were to start another WSL Ubuntu session at the same time, you will likely face issues if you don't enter the namespace.  For instance:

```
> sudo service xrdp status
Failed to retrieve unit state: Connection reset by peer
Failed to get properties: Connection reset by peer
```

This is because the `service` command detects that certain files in `/var/run` have been created by Systemd and attempts to use Systemd if so.

If you want to return to a "normal" WSL working environment, where Interop works (e.g. you can run Visual Studio Code), then you must (from PowerShell or CMD) `wsl --terminate <distroname>` (distroname is likely `Ubuntu`) and then restart WSL.